# How can I solve this error? ( ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()')

Tags: java

When I run this project, Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'error has occured. I clicked the given link, but it did not work! I cannot solve this problem. Can you help me?

Here is
build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }


    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]

when I clicked linked buttons, error message has occured

[image]

Comment: Try with upgrade that latest plugin.

Comment: Thank you for replying.. but it still doesn't work with 'war' plugin...

Comment: you have implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' wrong, please follow first default blank project to know basic android structure.

Comment: Ok I will thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the dependencies to the incorrect gradle file.

All the project dependencies (here `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`) should go into your app's `build.gradle` file.

Look at your project structure closely, there must be 2 build.gradle files there, add this dependency to the other gradle file.